# Replacing `String.prototype.valueOf` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) which would benefit from being able to hack some JS internals. I understand this is a very bad idea in general JS usage, but for my purposes it's okay. The following code works fine:

```
var str = new String("blah");
str.valueOf = function() { return 10 }
console.log(str * 10); // outputs 100
```

But this doesn't:

```
var str = "blah";
str.valueOf = function() { return 10 }
console.log(str * 10); // outputs NaN (because str === "blah")
```

Can someone who understands the internals a bit explain what's happening here? What's the underlying difference between these two examples?

And now what if I want to change the String prototype itself, so I can set the `valueOf` method of *all strings*, no matter when/where/how they are created? Is this possible? Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work:

```
String.prototype.valueOf = function() { return 10 }
console.log("blah" * 10); // NaN
```

Though this does:

```
String.prototype.valueOf = function() { return 10 }
console.log("blah".valueOf() * 10); // 100
```

And so does this:

```
String.prototype.valueOf = function() { return 10 }
console.log(new String("blah") * 10); // 100
```

Why does the JS engine treat `"blah"` and `new String("blah")` differently? Thanks!

By the way, [here is a good article](http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html) that sort of led me to explore this stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
var str = "blah";
```

you're creating a string **primitive**, but when you do

```
var str = new String("blah");
```

you're invoking the constructor and creating a String **object**.

When you have an object, javascript internally calls `valueOf` when trying to use that object where a primitive should be inserted.

For primitives it's the opposite, to be able to chain on methods, javascript needs an object, and internally primitives are wrapped with `new String` when calling object methods on the primitive.

In other words, when you have a string primitive, and you try to call `str.valueOf`, javascript will internally do `new String(str)` before it calls `valueOf` and returns the value.
However when you try to use the string direcly you still just have the primitive, and `valueOf` isn't called, the primitive value is inserted direcly.

From MDN

> Note that JavaScript distinguishes between `String` objects and
>   primitive string values. (The same is true of `Boolean` and `Numbers`.)
>
> String literals *(denoted by double or single quotes)* and strings
>   returned from `String` calls in a non-constructor context *(i.e., without
>   using the `new` keyword)* are primitive strings.
>
> JavaScript automatically
>   converts primitives to `String` objects, so that it's possible to use
>   `String` object methods for primitive strings.
>
> In contexts where a
>   method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup
>   occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and
>   call the method or perform the property lookup.

Comment: "In contexts where a method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and call the method or perform the property lookup." - very sneaky! But that makes sense. Great answer, thanks :)